# Check my logic on direct and indirect effects

Tags: regression, statistical-power, path-model

Skill A and Skill B are both directly related to Skill C.  Skill C is directly related to Skill D.  Skill A and B do not have significant direct relationships with Skill D.

Skill A and B can be considered components of Skill C--for example, A and B might be vocabulary and grammar knowledge, while C is listening comprehension.

Am I right in making the following suggestions?

1. In an analysis that excludes Skill C (e.g. a regression or a path analysis), a relationship between Skill A and Skill D probably won't emerge unless the study has a lot of data points.  So for example, if we do a study with 100 individuals we might find there is no relation between A and D, but if we include 2000 we might find a small, significant relation.
2. In a study that includes Skills A, B, and D (not Skill C), we may find no relation between A and D or B and D, but if we combined A and B into a single latent factor, we may find a relation between the latent factor and Skill D even though no other changes were made (e.g. no changes in how skills are measured, same number of subjects, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. When you omit "Skill C" from analyses, the relations between Skills A and B with D are considered a "total effect" which is the sum of direct and indirect effects. While you claim a lack of direct effects are present, the non-zero indirect effect will be detectable, albeit with an accumulation of measurement error. Nothing in general can be said about the power of the analysis without clear statements about the measurement error, and path effects relating the entire DAG.
2. This is just an instrumental variables analysis. It's true that if the causal model is such that A and B function as manifest variables, they jointly predict a latent variable which may have greater power to detect a relationship between D and C than between D and A and B in separate analyses. The main rationale for conducting such an analysis, however, is that one truly *believes* C is a latent trait and that A and B function as manifest variables, and not, say, colliders (traits which are caused by C and D) or confounders (traits which *cause* C and D). Some would advocate conducting an exploratory factor analysis to "confirm" these aspects of such a model before doing a confirmatory analysis, but I think this introduces additional problems. A CFA is not powered to distinguish between manifest variables, confounders, and colliders, it is an identifiability problem. Rather, one should state the conceptual model they're working from and cite the limitations of both the model and the data to really establish causality.